# How to checked Checkbox Codeigniter from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, checkbox

i have some problem here about checkbox if radio button can be solved  by using this script in the view

```
enter code here
   <input type="radio" name="jk" value="L" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', 'L', ($detail->jk == "L") ? TRUE : FALSE ); ?> >L

  <input type="radio" name="jk" value="P" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', 'P', ($detail->jk == "P") ? TRUE : FALSE ); ?>>P
```

but for check box why it cant be solved by using this script

```
enter code here

   <input type="checkbox" name="hoby" value="Lari" <?php echo set_checkbox('hoby', '($detail->hoby=="Lari")'); ?> />Lari

    <input type="checkbox" name="hoby" value="Berenang" <?php echo set_checkbox('hoby', '($detail->hoby=="Berenang")'); ?> />Berenang
```

i was new bie at Code Igniter

any way big thanks for answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hoby" value="Lari" <?php echo set_checkbox('hoby', 'Lari')'); ?> />Lari

<input type="checkbox" name="hoby" value="Berenang" <?php echo set_checkbox('hoby', 'Berenang'); ?> />Berenang
```

To fully understand the concept please go through the following tutorial on Form Helpers in CodeIgniter: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

**EDIT - 1:**

I must say, it's a very very unclear question.

What I was able to understand from your question is, you are intending to save `varchar` values to the database based on checking/unchecking a checkbox??????? Well, all I know is that you can only save `boolean` or `integer` values of 1/0 when you check/uncheck a checkbox.

Try using javascript or jQuery. And please change your database column from `varchar` to `int`. Your php variable should also contain `int` values instead of `string` on checkbox check/uncheck.

This might help:

View:

```
   <input type="checkbox" id="hoby_l" value="1" 
   <?php 
   if ($hoby_Lary == 1) 
   { 
   ?> 
       checked = "true" 
   <?php 
   } 
   ?> onchange = "valueChanged()";
   />

  <input type="checkbox" id="hoby_b" value="1" 
  <?php 
  if ($hoby_Berenang == 1) 
  { 
  ?> 
      checked = "true" 
  <?php 
  } 
  ?> onchange = "valueChanged()";
  />
```

JavaScript:

```
    function valueChanged() 
    {

        if(document.getElementById('hoby_l').checked == 'true')
        {


             document.getElementById('hoby_b').checked == 'false';
             return 1;
        }
        else
        {
              return 0;
        }

        if(document.getElementById('hoby_b').checked == 'true')
        {

             document.getElementById('hoby_l').checked == 'false';
             return 1;

        }
        else
        {
              return 0;
        } 

    }
```

A sincere word of advice: You need to improve your English while asking question, otherwise it's difficult for the community to help you. How can you expect help while you can't explain properly what your problem is?

Another sincere word of advice: No matter how hard it looks, please don't try to avoid the User Guide. You don't understand it's importance right now. But it'll help you a lot in future.

Comment: it doesn't help mr, i already read user guide about helper but so hard understand it !

i want that everything store in database when show in system it suppose to be checked, i'm sorry for stupid question but really i'm new bie at Code igniter, Big Thanks

Comment: Well I can understand your feelings, but you have to refer to the standard references. CodeIgniter User Guide is designed for that purpose. Also please let me know if my solution works.

Comment: doesnt work uncle, if any suggest  or some script to make it running well, please help me Crescent Moon

Answer (score 0):

```
    if((int) $checked == 1){//do what you want}

    OR Try this

    create one funciton in your model file like this

    function get_checkbox_value($check) {

            for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {

                $result[$i] = '';

            }

            foreach($check as $chk) {

                for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {

                    if(($i+1) == $chk['ID']) {

                        $result[$i] = 'checked';

                        continue;

                    } 

                }

            }

            return $result;

        }
    and your view file call function like this


   <input type="checkbox" id="lari" name="hoby" value="2" <?php echo empty($check) ? '' : $check[1]; ?>/>
```

Comment: i'm still dont get it mr, can you explained more, sorry for hard understanding code igniter, so where kueri call check box it self, is that $check ? i'm sorry